# SELECT multiple rows, each having multiple related rows in another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

What is a recommended way to return all data from `Orders` and `Orderitems` to make the display (see below)?  I would also like `qty` information to be available, because I intend to use it as a tooltip when I hover over any product id.  Thanks.

1) If I use 1 query with an INNER JOIN, I will replicate the order data in each row. It would multiple the size of the returned data by 1..N times.  I would discard the replicated data before returning the JSON to my front-end.  But is this a bad practice?

2) If I use 2 queries with paging `LIMIT 10` I won't know which `ids` were used in my 2nd query if ids are not a perfect increase (because some were deleted.)

Orders

```
+----+--------+
| id | custid |
+----+--------+
|  1 |     43 |
|  2 |    843 |
|  3 |     12 |
+----+--------+
```

Orderitems

```
+----+--------------+---------------+-----+
| id | fk_orders_id | fk_product_id | qty |
+----+--------------+---------------+-----+
|  1 |            1 |          2454 |   1 |
|  2 |            1 |           153 |   2 |
|  3 |            1 |             2 |   1 |
|  4 |            2 |         25390 |   1 |
|  5 |            2 |          2214 |   2 |
|  6 |            3 |         11353 |   3 |
+----+--------------+---------------+-----+
```

Display

```
+----+--------------+---------------+
| id |    custid    | fk_product_id |
+----+--------------+---------------+
|  1 |           43 |    2454,153,2 |
|  2 |          843 |    25390,2214 |
|  3 |           12 |         11353 |
+----+--------------+---------------+
```

Comment: Add some sample table data (both tables), and the expected result. (All as well formatted text, not images.)

Comment: Please share Db structure with some data and what you want to display....

Comment: Use method 2, first fetch orders, then corresponding orderitems, maintain paging on Order, rather than whole array order and orderItems

Comment: @RanjeetSingh - thankyou

Comment: @jarlh I added some sample data.  I'm not sure how I would like to display the `Orderitems` data.  I will probably just want to show a comma delimited list of `fk_product_id`.  But I will want to send all data from that table back to the front end.  The problem is not of displaying, but to know what is the recommended practice to make the queries.

Comment: Prototype

 Fetch orders limit 0,10(mantain paging here)
 -> Make foreach loop for each orders to Find out the orderItems as well as other things
 -> Prepare an array

Comment: @Naincy I have added both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second option is correct. This contains few steps:

1) Get all your `Order` with pagination like this:

```
SELECT * FROM orders
WHERE id > 0
ORDER BY id ASC
LIMIT 10
```

2) In some empty array collect all fetched orders ids.

3) Get all corresponding `OrderItems` in any order you want like this:

```
SELECT * FROM order_items
WHERE order_id IN (1,2,3,4) // array of orders ids
ORDER BY id ASC // could use any order you want to
```

4) Iterate through fetched `OrderItems` and correspond it properly to `Order`.

3a) If you wish to fetch only few `OrderItems` for each `Order` you could use window function `ROW_NUMBER` like this one:

```
SELECT t.* FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY order_id ORDER BY id ASC) num FROM order_items
  WHERE order_id IN (1,2,3,4)
) t 
WHERE t.num <= 5 // if you wish only first 5 order items per each order
ORDER BY t.num ASC
```

Comment: I understand, thank you!  (And for the extra bit in 3a, I can study this.)

Comment: @dbquestions no problem, glad to help you)

Comment: For step #2, is there some easy way to collect all order ids?  (Especially if my ids are not sequential since some have been deleted.)

Comment: @dbquestions it really easy enough to do. I'm just not familiar with php. Suppose you have an array of N paginated `Order` called `orders` so you just write something like this: `order_ids = []; <iterate throgh orders with single order variable>; order_ids.push(order.id); `

Comment: oh I see, pull them from the result set afterwards.  ok, thanks!